# Ускорение полного перебора( брутфорса ) sha384,с использованиям gpu и многопоточности

Tags: python, gpu, sha, numba

Здраствуйте, мне надо "расшифровать" хеш, я знаю, что изначальный код состоит из 8 заглавный символов латинского алфавита и цифр, исходя из этого написал такой код, он последовательно перебирает комбинации из символов и цифр длинною строки в 8 знаков , потом хеширует и сверяет с нужным хешом, он как и полагалось, оказался слишком медленный для решения данной задачи, принялся изучать различные способы для работы с видеокартой и многопоточностью, решил использовать Anaconda3 и её библиотеки Numba, но к успеху не пришел, т.к новичок в программировании и не могу понять как сделать процесс многопоточным. Буду рад любой помощи, зарание спасибо

```
import hashlib
import sys, itertools
import time

sCharacters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
start_time = time.time()


for iCombinationLength in range(8, 9):
  for aCombination in itertools.product(sCharacters, repeat=iCombinationLength):
      code = (''.join(aCombination))
      h = hashlib.sha384( code.strip().encode( 'utf-8' ) )
      print(''.join(aCombination), h.hexdigest() )
      if  h.hexdigest() == '46a1ad5043379e9f643bedad39567e2e4dad5112159878a217166b8a06cf6a1528938114801651f1076cf2df6ed80d40' :
          print("success")
          print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
          break
```

Comment: Делать это на питоне — изначально гиблая идея, возьмите hashcat и не надо ничего программировать

Comment: В любом случае это задача практически безнадёжная, если делать именно просто перебор. Никакими средствами вы в разумные сроки не уложитесь. Вот если есть специальные программы, использующие какие-то особенности данного хэша, чтобы проверять его быстрее за счёт каких-то специальных хаков - тогда ещё есть шансы. Просто посчитайте, сколько у вас примерно один хэш проверяется и прикиньте, насколько нужно ускорить код, чтобы он посчитал за разумное время.

Comment: можно посмотреть на https://crackstation.net/ - хотя там не распознало хеш.